# Xcode error in linker

Tags: iphone, xcode

i am new iPhone developer. i got this error.

> Ld
>   /Users/c4ntechnology/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPatientCare-azwpvvrjjoaoygfcfqiicwkyssya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPatientCare.app/iPatientCare
>   normal i386
>       cd /Users/c4ntechnology/Desktop/iPatientCare
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/c4ntechnology/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPatientCare-azwpvvrjjoaoygfcfqiicwkyssya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/c4ntechnology/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPatientCare-azwpvvrjjoaoygfcfqiicwkyssya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/c4ntechnology/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPatientCare-azwpvvrjjoaoygfcfqiicwkyssya/Build/Intermediates/iPatientCare.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPatientCare.build/Objects-normal/i386/iPatientCare.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -lsqlite3 -framework UIKit -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/c4ntechnology/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPatientCare-azwpvvrjjoaoygfcfqiicwkyssya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPatientCare.app/iPatientCare
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

please help me

Comment: It looks like you're missing a framework.

Comment: Do you have a class called ViewController? If you do, import it in AppDelegate. If you don't remove references to ViewController from your AppDelegate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This compiler error means your `AppDelegate` class is referencing the `ViewController` class in your project, but the `ViewController` isn't currently set up to be compiled and included in the final product.

To make sure the `ViewController` class is included in the final product, select the blue Xcode project icon in the upper left column like shown in the image below:

[image]

Then select your target in the next column over, then select the `Build Phases` tab, and make sure `ViewController.m` is included in the list along with `AppDelegate.m` and others like shown. To add it if it's not currently there, you can drag the icon of it in the very leftmost column and drop it into the Compile Sources table view, or click the + button at the bottom of that table view.

Answer (score 0):

The UIKit class is called `UIViewController`, you are most likely missing the "UI" part. You have to import `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` to use this class, but it is most likely already included in your `MyApp-Prefix.pch`. If ViewController is a class of your own, you must:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```